# are customViews for UIBarButtonItems ignored for the leftBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

From the documentation, I see this for the backBarButtonItem:

> When this property is nil, the navigation item uses the value in its
>   title (page 10) property to create an appropriate back button. If you
>   want to specify a custom image or title for the back button, you can
>   assign a custom bar button item (with your custom title or image) to
>   this property instead. When configuring your bar button item, do not
>   assign a custom view to it; the navigation item ignores custom views
>   in the back bar button anyway.

I didn't know if this was the same for leftBarButtonItem?  Basically I have this code:

```
UIButton *homeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
UIImage *homeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_house.png"];
[homeButton setImage:homeImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[homeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(homePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *homeBBI = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:homeButton];
```

Prior to iOS 5, I put this in a UIToolBar and it showed up fine.  Now I want to put this as the leftBarButtonItem, to the right of the UINavigationController's backButton.  When I set it, it does not show up at all.  There is no image.  However, when I create some button like this:

```
    UIBarButtonItem *hButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"home" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(homePressed:)];
```

and set it as the leftBarButtonItem, it shows up.  I didn't know how I could get my custom icon for my home button without the borders.  When I use:

```
    UIBarButtonItem *hButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_house.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(homePressed:)];
```

I get a border around my house_icon that i do not want.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
UIButton *TastoVersamento = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [TastoVersamento setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Versamento.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [TastoVersamento addTarget:self action:@selector(Click_Versamento:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [TastoVersamento setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
        [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:TastoVersamento] autorelease]];
```

Answer (score 1):

`backBarButtonItem` and `leftBarButtonItem` are different. `backBarButtonItem` is the default if no `leftBarButtonItem` is given. It will also show up even if `leftBarButtonItem` is set if `leftItemsSupplementBackButton` is `YES`.

In your first example, you could try `[homeButton sizeToFit]`. I think the frame may not be getting set correctly.

But as to your last comment, I *think* you won't be succesful in removing the border from navigation item buttons. I'm pretty sure they're hard coded. In fact, if you add a button that has a border, you'll get two, one from the button and one from the navigation item.

Comment: Crud. You set the frame ahead of time ... In any case, I think your second example is what you want: `initWithImage`. (A button inside a button is weird.) `initWithImage` is what I do. And as I said, I don't believe you'll be able to remove the border.